# Append text as first line to all outgoing mail in Service Cloud

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud

While exchanging mail from Desk.com, 'Type your response ABOVE THIS LINE to reply' is appended automatically to the message sent. How can I replicate the same with Service Cloud?

Thanks.[image: Type your response ABOVE THIS LINE]

Comment: if you can elaborate with a screenshot, that might help to understand your requirement.

Comment: @SantanuBoral, Apologies for the delay in response. I have added an image to my question.